# Range Slider - Run function during slide not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I am using [noUISlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) on a page to allow a person to choose a value. The noUISlider words, however, when a person is sliding I would like it to run a function that basically checks the number and if the number is below a certain value it will display text in a div.

The problem is that the value is recorded in the hidden input but the function to display the text never works.

Here is my code for the function:

```
var heightSlide = $('.height-noUI');
var onSlide = function(){
    var slideHeight = "$('input[name=CAT_Custom_8]').val();"
    if(slideHeight <= 20){
        $('.height-noUI-text').text('Short');
    }else if(slideHeight <= 40){
        $('.height-noUI-text').text('Short to Medium');
    }else if(slideHeight <= 60){
        $('.height-noUI-text').text('Medium');
    }else if(slideHeight <= 80){
        $('.height-noUI-text').text('Medium to Tall');
    }else if(slideHeight <= 100){
        $('.height-noUI-text').text('Tall');
    }
};
heightSlide.on('slide', onSlide);
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn9E3/1/) of the code with a working slider.

How do I update my code to work so the text is displayed in the div when the slider slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem. Checkout the code for understand.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn9E3/2/)

```
$(function() {

    $(".height-noUI").noUiSlider({
       range: [0, 100],
       start: 0,
        range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
        },
       step: 20,
       connect: "lower",
       serialization: {
          lower: [
              $.Link({
                  target: $("input[name=CAT_Custom_8]")
              })
          ],
          format: {
            decimals: 0
          }
       }
    });

    var heightSlide = $('.height-noUI');
    var onSlide = function(){
        var slideHeight = $('.noUi-origin').position().left / $('.noUi-origin').parent().width() * 100; //Here is the trick.
        if(slideHeight <= 20){
            $('.height-noUI-text').text('Short');
        }else if(slideHeight <= 40){
            $('.height-noUI-text').text('Short to Medium');
        }else if(slideHeight <= 60){
            $('.height-noUI-text').text('Medium');
        }else if(slideHeight <= 80){
            $('.height-noUI-text').text('Medium to Tall');
        }else if(slideHeight <= 100){
            $('.height-noUI-text').text('Tall');
        }
    };
    heightSlide.on('slide', onSlide);

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Question: When the input shows 20 it should display Short, however, it displays Short to Medium. How do I fix that?

Comment: It should be working in the jsfiddle. I tested it now. 20 => Short

Comment: I realize what is happening. `slideHeight` was something like 20.00000153354664 thus larger than 20. I added `Math.floor()` to solve the issue. [Here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jn9E3/5/).

Comment: Good job, I am happy to help you.